# Wix - custom action still executed after removal

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action

In a Wix 3.6 installer code, I have a custom action. When I remove it from the code and recompile, the custom action is still executed, as if I didn't remove it (I can see it from the log after running the command "msiexec /i MyInstaller.msi /l*v MyLog.txt"). I tried to change the name of the file and remove intermediar files but the bug is still here. When I change something else (remove a feature for example), the execution of the msi is as expected except for the custom action. So it seems to happen only with custom actions.

How can this happen ?

Comment: If that MSI ProductCode guid is already installed you'd see something like that. Your install will go into maintenance mode and reinstall the existing product, not your new one.

Comment: Thanks, I changed ProductCode and UpgradeCode and it's ok now !